# How to parse .chm files in perl?

Tags: perl, chm

How to parse .chm files in perl ? Which module is used for it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about [Archive::Chm](http://p3rl.org/Archive::Chm)?

> Performs some read-only operations on
>   HTML help (.chm) files. Range of
>   operations includes enumerating
>   contents, extracting contents and
>   getting information about one certain
>   part of the archive